# ASP.NET WebApi2/MVC5 cookie authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to implement cookie authentication. Here is my login action:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Login([FromBody]string email)
{
    var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(email);
    Authentication.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    var identity = 
                   await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user,
                   DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie); 
                   // identity.IsAuthenticated is true, why?
    Authentication.SignIn(identity); // identity is correct (name is user@user.com), i checked it
    // User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is false here
    return Ok();
}
```

Authentication is:

```
private IAuthenticationManager Authentication
{
    get
    {
        return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
    }
}
```

But User.Identity.Name is still empty. What i'm doing wrong? How can i get authenticated user?

Here is my Startup.Auth:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    static Startup()
    {
        var userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new UserStore<IdentityUser>(new MyDbContext()));
        userManager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<IdentityUser>(userManager)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
        };
        UserManagerFactory = () => userManager;
    }

    public static Func<UserManager<IdentityUser>> UserManagerFactory { get; set; }

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting SignIn method like this

```
  private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
        {
            get
            {
                return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
            }
        }
```

```
 public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Login([FromBody]string email)
    {
        var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(email);
        Authentication.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
        return Ok();
    }
```

Comment: didn't help. i forget to say that my Authentication is HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication. changing isPersistent also didn't help

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to remove the following code:

```
Authentication.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
```